# Unable to delete data from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im using POSTMAN to delete contact using id and it returns

```
{
   "n": 0,
   "ok": 1
}
```

#### This is my delete code so far

```
router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  contact.remove({ _id: new objectId(req.params._id) }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What request do you send?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the _id value as an ObjectID, not a string:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next) => {
      contact.deleteOne({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.params._id) }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(result);
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that OP doesn't provide or provide incorrect `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

`id !== _id`

change `:id` in your route to `:_id` and you should be fine.